# TB6600 / using with low voltage stepper motor

Tags: transistors, voltage-divider, stepper-motor, stepper-driver

I'm using a classic TB6600 Stepper Motor driver (see for example [link](https://www.watelectronics.com/tb6600-stepper-motor-driver-module/))

I have a stepper motor that is rated for 5 VDC [(datasheet)](https://www.haydonkerkpittman.com/products/motors/canstack-rotary-motors/20mm-z20000).  I have the datasheet, but it does not specify a current limit.  I assume that at 5 VDC, the current limit is implied by the resistance of the coils?

It seems to me that when I use a 12 VDC supply to the TB6600, I'm going to get more than 5 VDC on the stepper motor.  The current limiting of 0.5 A in the TB6600 may not be enough to prevent a motor meltdown!

How do I deal with this?

- Add a current limiting resistor to each coil?
- Measure the voltage across the coils from the driver and build a voltage divider and supply only 5 VDC to the motor?
- Use transistors on each coil and use the driver to switch on/off 5 VDC source to the coils on the motor?

Comment: Have you measured the resistance of the motor coil with an ohm meter?

Comment: These coils are 20 Ohms.

Comment: So, it looks like the rated current is 5V divided by 20 ohms equals 0.25 amps.

Comment: If your TB6600 driver only goes down to 0.5 amps, you have a problem! Best solution may be to find a stepper motor with rated current of 0.5 amps or more.  How many wires does the motor have?

Comment: Do you have a link to the motor specifications?

Comment: https://www.haydonkerkpittman.com/products/motors/canstack-rotary-motors/20mm-z20000